# How to retrive items path in CSV file using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have Following PowerShell Script which downloads documents from document library with folders to a local drive. it also downloads metadata of each document in CSV file. How do I copy the folder path of each document in same CSV file?

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$destination = "C:\\FolderName\\"
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://XYZ:2010/"
$list = $web.GetList("http://XYZ:2010/Shared Documents/")


function ProcessFolder {
    param($folderUrl)
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
        #Ensure destination directory
        $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
        {
            $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
        }
        #Download file
        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()

    }
}
$exportlist = @()
$list.Items | foreach {
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
"Title" = $_["Title"]
"Name" = $_["Name"]
"Modified Date" = $_["Modified"]
"Modified By" =$_["Modified By"]
"Size"= $_["File Size"]

}
$exportlist += $obj
$exportlist | Export-Csv -path 'C:\FolderName\MyList.csv' -noType
}


#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
}
#DownloadMetadata ($list.RootFolder.Url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SPListItem.File.Url` to get the the relative url of the file. And `SPWeb.Url` to get the url of the web and combine them together. In your code use:

```
"Path" = $web.Url + "/" + $_.File.Url
```

The code may look something like this. Note: I have not tested it. But it will give you an idea how to go with your scenario:

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$destination = "C:\\FolderName\\"
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://XYZ:2010/"
$list = $web.GetList("http://XYZ:2010/Shared Documents/")
$exportlist = @()

function ProcessFolder {
    param($folderUrl)
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
        $item = $file.ListItem
        #Ensure destination directory
        $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
        {
            $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
        }
        #Download file
        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
        $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Title" = $item["Title"]
        "Name" = $item["Name"]
        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
        "Modified By" =$item["Modified By"]
        "Size"= $item["File Size"]

    }
}

$exportlist += $obj
$exportlist | Export-Csv -path 'C:\FolderName\MyList.csv' -noType
}


#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
}
#DownloadMetadata ($list.RootFolder.Url)
```

Comment: Thanks A lot. i can maintain log as well in same CSV file using above code?

Comment: what do you mean by log?

Comment: means I have to maintain a log of documents which gets downloaded succesfully or not

Comment: The code for downloading the files and exporting the info to Excel is working in two different loops. You may have to move the export code inside the download code to be able to update a flag is CSV file once a document is downloaded. Remember to get the List item from file in the download code using $file.ListItem

Comment: See my updated answer. As mentioned it is not tested.

Comment: I already did that. But I am not sure about log thing

Comment: You need to write the code for download in a try catch block. And add one more column like Status in the export. So when the code in try block executes successfully you update Status column with success and if it gets into catch block update the Status with failure.